# Invoking cmd.exe from java without arguments

Tags: java, io, java-io

I am writing few programs to invoke cmd.exe with additional commands and collect the output generated from the same using java. Below is a sample program--

```
public class LoadShell {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Line1
        String [] command ={"cmd.exe","/c","dir"};      
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );             
        Process process = probuilder.start();       
        InputStream inputstream1 = process.getInputStream();        
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader1 = new InputStreamReader(inputstream1);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader1);      
        String line="";
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

  }
}
```

These programs are working fine as expected. Now I have a simpler requirement. I want to invoke cmd.exe without any arguments and collect the output as String. This is because I want to send the process object reference and string to another method for some project specific purpose. So I have modified my code in Line1 as below--

```
public class LoadShell {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          //Line1
      String [] command ={"cmd.exe"};
      ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder( command );             
          Process process = probuilder.start(); 
          InputStream inputstream1 = process.getInputStream();        
          InputStreamReader inputstreamreader1 = new InputStreamReader(inputstream1);
          BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader1);
          int intch;     
        String line="";
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

       }
}
```

But in this case, the `readLine` method hangs indefinitely after printing--

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

So I have also tried using read of `BufferedReader` instead of `readline` as follows --

```
while ((intch = bufferedreader.read()) != -1) {
            int ch = (char) intch;
            System.out.println(ch);
          }
```

But even read is hanging after reading the bytes corresponding to --

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Is there any way I can get the complete output that is below without causing my program to hang --

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\devshankhasharm>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: When you invoke only with cmd.exe the command window does not open. It only gives partial output in the console and hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Yes I am, you can actually run my program and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because without the `/c` flag you're simply opening a shell window, and that external process is now sitting at the `C:\>` prompt waiting for a command to be issued. Since you never send anything, it'll sit there until you kill it.